# Python: memory store in separate process

Tags: python, memcached, twisted

I'm building a server in Python and am thinking of keeping the memory store in a separate process so that the processes with business logic can be easily upgraded and maintained. I think memcached might be what I'm looking for, but in my cursory inspection, it seems not to store python objects so well (Twisted connection objects).

What is the easiest way to pass (key:value) objects between python processes? As this is in Twisted, the most asynchronous-friendly approach is what I'm after.

General feedback on this design is also appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you're making your life harder without a good reason.  Keep everything in one process until you actually know you'll benefit from multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `Queue` and `Pipe` classes from the `multiprocessing` module. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) has examples.

Comment: The `multiprocessing` module is async-unfriendly.